# Derivative of tensor function of single variable

Tags: linear-algebra, differential-geometry, tensors, multilinear-algebra, exterior-algebra

Let $V =(v_{1} \wedge \ldots \wedge v_{k})$ be a smooth curve in the $k$-th exterior power $\Lambda^{k}(\mathbb{R}^{n})$ of $\mathbb{R}^{n}$.

In the case $n=3$ and $k=2$, I believe the following holds:
$$\frac{dV}{dt} = \frac{dv_{1}}{dt} \wedge v_{2} + v_{1} \wedge \frac{dv_{2}}{dt}.$$

I would like to know how the above relation generalizes to the case $k=n-1$. For example, when $n=4$ and $k=3$, is that true that
$$\frac{dV}{dt} = \frac{dv_{1}}{dt} \wedge v_{2} \wedge v_{3}\ + v_{1} \wedge \frac{dv_{2}}{dt} \wedge v_{3} + v_{1} \wedge v_{2} \wedge \frac{dv_{3}}{dt}?$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The generalization you expect is correct and it works for any $k$ and $n$. What you need in order to prove this is just the fact how to differentiate multilinear maps between vector spaces, and apply this to the map $(\mathbb R^n)^k\to\bigwedge^k(\mathbb R^n)$ defined by $(v_1,\dots,v_k)\mapsto v_1\wedge\dots\wedge v_k$.

**Edit**: If you have a multilinear map $\Phi:V_1\times\dots\times V_k\to V$, then the derivative $D\Phi(v_1,\dots,v_k)(w_1,\dots,w_k)$ (with $v_i,w_i\in V_i$) can be computed as a directional derivative. So you consider the curve $\Phi(v_1+tw_1,\dots,v_k+tw_k)$, differentiate with respect to $t$ and evaluate at $t=0$. Using linearity in each component, you can expand $\Phi(v_1+tw_1,\dots,v_k+tw_k)$ in powers of $t$, and you want to find the coefficient of $t$. This is just the sum of all terms in which one $v$ is replaced by the corresponding $w$, i.e. $\Phi(w_1,v_2,\dots,v_k)+\dots+\Phi(v_1,\dots,v_{k-1},w_k)$.

Comment: Thanks for the help! I was hoping to find a proof without introducing coordinates. But I am not able to differentiate maps between general vector spaces (without using charts). Could you please give me some hint?

Comment: I have edited the reply adding some information.

Comment: That's great, thanks a lot.